# Is there a way to change the id from a text into an integer?

Tags: json, swift, database, sqlite

I am trying to save data from an API into SQLite through blackbird package in xcode SwiftUI. however, it requires a variable named id to be an integer, but the ID provided by the API is a string. I don't know how to make this work.

```
struct Meal: Identifiable, Codable, BlackbirdModel{
    @BlackbirdColumn var idMeal: String
    @BlackbirdColumn var strMeal: String
    @BlackbirdColumn var strMealThumb: String
}
```

I am fairly new to SwiftUI, and I am trying to create an app that gets data from this API https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=beef. I have successfully done this. And the next step was to create a button that saves the meal you wanted to a list. I wanted to save the data into SQLite through Blackbird. The problem is that the Blackbird package requires you to have a property named id that is an integer. The id provided by the API is a string. If I try to run the program it will sat 'Fatal Error in blackbirdschema.swift" "Must specify a primary key or have a property named "id" to automatically use as primary key." How would I make this work?

Comment: SwiftUI, which is a UI and lifecycle management framework, likely is irrelevant here -- it's just Swift.

Comment: Can’t you create a computed property that uses idMeal then? idMeal is already an integer and since it seems to be an identifier it should be mandatory but maybe you can check that in the api documentation.

Comment: Correcting my previous comment, idMeal isn’t a native Int but it should be easy to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are techniques to convert strings to integers (with custom `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` implementation). But you do not need to do that here. Neither `Identifiable` nor `BlackbirdModel` require the id/key be an integer. Sure, their example uses an `Int`, but anything unique (and hashable) will do the job.

To simplify life, you can just define your type to be:

```swift
struct Meal: BlackbirdModel {
    static var primaryKey: [BlackbirdColumnKeyPath] = [\.$idMeal]

    @BlackbirdColumn var idMeal: String
    @BlackbirdColumn var strMeal: String
    @BlackbirdColumn var strMealThumb: URL
}
```

---

[Blackbird](https://github.com/marcoarment/Blackbird#blackbird-database) has been [fixed](https://github.com/marcoarment/Blackbird/commit/df005eec618771d2abd7a675b8e1815ad4b09c5c) to support custom `CodingKeys`. So, with that, I would be inclined to define `Meal` as follows:

```swift
struct Meal: BlackbirdModel, Identifiable {
    @BlackbirdColumn var id: String
    @BlackbirdColumn var name: String
    @BlackbirdColumn var thumbnail: URL

    enum CodingKeys: String, BlackbirdCodingKey {
        case id = "idMeal"
        case name = "strMeal"
        case thumbnail = "strMealThumb"
    }
}
```

This is `Identifiable` and replaces the poor key names of the JSON with something far better. And we use the string keys provided by the web service.